# Magento2 customer account navigation change 3column page layout

Tags: layout, magento2

on customer_account.xml I've changed to the below code in
`VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`
but changes doesn't reflect on the frontend eventhough I've deployed codes. Also tried changing in `VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

What could be the issue?

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1):

**VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml
Replace the below Line
        Search below Code

layout="2columns-left"

replace to

layout="3columns"

run the Below Command : 
php bin/magento cache:flush & php bin/magneto cache:clean & then Try